# Live stream a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube, youtube-api, wowza

Is it possible to live stream (youtube) a specific react component? I have some financial charts using web sockets that I would like to put on a live youtube channel, but not sure where to start.

I can only find documentation and packages around youtube to react, rather than the other way around.

---

I know that I could make my webcam stream my desktop and broadcast live that way, but I still need to use my computer and don't want to show mouse movements, different tabs etc.

Thanks

Comment: It's possible. For youtube you need a video of an element, so check https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC and for some demos, maybe https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/simple-demos/screen-recording.html

You can record even a tab that's in background, so then you just figure out how to stream that video with OBS.

Comment: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/simple-demos/recording-html-element.html